# Send data between specific users in socket based app

Tags: python, ios, sockets, network-programming, twisted

I have two kinds of user in my app, let's say an A and a B user. I have a data base with a one-to-many relationship between A and B, so A can have multiple B's and B just one A.

I need to send data from A to its B's and from a B to its A.

I'm following the Raywenderlich's socket based app and server tuturial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/, this tutorial allows the user to connect the server and send data to all other users conected, a chat room. For that a protocol is created to identify an user: iam:username

how can i specific send data only to users in a relationship, instead of any conected user like is shown in the tutorial?

The tutorial create a server using Python and Twisted, here is the code used:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


    class IphoneChat(Protocol):
        def connectionMade(self):
            #self.transport.write("""connected""")
            self.factory.clients.append(self)
            print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

        def connectionLost(self, reason):
            self.factory.clients.remove(self)

        def dataReceived(self, data):
            #print "data is ", data
            a = data.split(':')
            if len(a) > 1:
                command = a[0]
                content = a[1]

                msg = ""
                if command == "iam":
                    self.name = content
                    msg = self.name + " has joined"

                elif command == "msg":
                    msg = self.name + ": " + content

                print msg

                for c in self.factory.clients:
                    c.message(msg)

        def message(self, message):
            self.transport.write(message + '\n')


    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = IphoneChat
    factory.clients = []

    reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
    print "Iphone Chat server started"
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the code:

```
for c in self.factory.clients:
   c.message(msg)
```

You should customize the message object by including the destination. Then in this server code, send the message only to the right one.

Comment: It will be a good approach? It will do the job, but i will have to reach every client connected for that. There is any kind of p2p aproach to directly send data to specifc users without search among all connected users?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not p2p approach. This is a server that you connect to. It a chat server.

For a p2P approach, you can customize the code of this server script to let an iPhone find a partner. Then communicate directly with him.

So, the solution is: 
- You keep this server script to tracking for clients connected to the server
- Whenever a client want to communicate with another, it will contact the server to ask if this client is connected or not, and what are necessary infos in order to communicate with him (IP, port).
- If the server response is ok, you create a socket directly to that client.